# Man's wife turns back into a monster when he talks about it

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, horror

I'd say it's a movie from the 80's or 90's.

At one point the main character sees a monster in the street (I'd say at night, in an alley).  It's quite a big monster and the monster can talk.  They talk and the guy is frightened and the monster agrees to spare his life under one condition: that the man never ever talks to anyone about the monster. So the man agrees.

Then life goes on.  He meets a girl and they have kids (if I recall correctly, not 100% sure about the kids).

But then the guy is not doing well: he thinks about that monster he saw years ago all too often. Eventually after years of silence (I think years went by because I think they did have kids), he breaks the deal and talks about the monster to his friend / wife. And the wife starts screaming / yelling at him and...  she turns back into the monster.

Not too sure about what happen next.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is [Tales From the Darkside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Darkside%3a_The_Movie), the movie. The monster is Tommy Chong's daughter (IRL), I believe.

It was 1 of about 3 or 4 stories in the whole thing.

Answer (score 20):

It sounds like the third segment of *Tales from the Darkside: The Movie* -

> A despondent artist named Preston (played by James Remar) witnesses a
>   gruesome murder by a gargoyle-like monster. The monster gets Preston
>   to swear to never speak of what he saw in exchange for a promise to
>   spare his life. After making the promise, Preston meets a beautiful
>   woman named Carola (played by Rae Dawn Chong). Preston marries Carola,
>   they have two kids, and Preston has a revival of his art career. But
>   Preston was still tormented by guilt about his silence, and started
>   reconsidering the promise he made to the monster.
>
> Preston then tells Carola about that night ten years ago when they met
>   after he had witnessed the killing of a man by a monster which he
>   sculpted to show her. After releasing a heartbroken screech, Carola
>   reveals herself to be the very same creature he made the promise with,
>   lamenting that the promise Preston made to the monster had been
>   broken. As such, she reverts to her previous form, and their children
>   transform into similar monsters as well. Within the shock and despair
>   of such revelations, Preston is killed at 'her' hands, and she escapes
>   through a skylight with their children. The final scene shows that the
>   gargoyle and children have turned to stone upon a building ledge,
>   staring down at Preston's body in remorse. (Wikipedia)

[image]